# Get center in Cesium Map

Tags: gis, cesiumjs

I need to know what is the current center of the Cesium Map.

I tried to use `viewer.camera.position` but it always gives the same z value (x: 16921255.101297915, y: 5578093.302269477, z: 12756274) and I'm not sure about the x and y values. Are they in meters?

Thanks a lot!

EDIT: Solution

With all the help I got (thanks!) I put this together:

```
getPosition(){
    if (viewer.scene.mode == 3) {
        var windowPosition = new Cesium.Cartesian2(viewer.container.clientWidth / 2, viewer.container.clientHeight / 2);
        var pickRay = viewer.scene.camera.getPickRay(windowPosition);
        var pickPosition = viewer.scene.globe.pick(pickRay, viewer.scene);
        var pickPositionCartographic = viewer.scene.globe.ellipsoid.cartesianToCartographic(pickPosition);
        console.log(pickPositionCartographic.longitude * (180 / Math.PI));
        console.log(pickPositionCartographic.latitude * (180 / Math.PI));
    } else if (viewer.scene.mode == 2) {
        var camPos = viewer.camera.positionCartographic;
        console.log(camPos.longitude * (180 / Math.PI));
        console.log(camPos.latitude * (180 / Math.PI));
    }
};
```

This function gives longitude/latitude coordinates in degrees.

Comment: Yes, Cartesian values are in meters.  The X axis points from the center of the Earth out towards Lat 0, Lon 0, Alt 0.  The Z axis points from the center out towards the North Pole.  The Y axis forms a right-hand coordinate system with the other two.  You have to use `Ellipsoid.cartesianToCartographic` (shown in the answer below) to perform the conversion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**viewer.camera.position** gives you the position at which camera is located in X,Y,Z coordinates in meters in relation to earth center.

Depending on which scene mode you are using approach is different:

**SCENE3D:**

In order to see at what is the camera looking at you need to get the intersect point of camera's pick ray and map.

```
 function getMapCenter() {            
        var windowPosition = new Cesium.Cartesian2(viewer.container.clientWidth / 2, viewer.container.clientHeight / 2);
        var pickRay = viewer.scene.camera.getPickRay(windowPosition);
        var pickPosition = viewer.scene.globe.pick(pickRay, viewer.scene);
        var pickPositionCartographic = viewer.scene.globe.ellipsoid.cartesianToCartographic(pickPosition);
        console.log(pickPositionCartographic.longitude * (180/Math.PI));
        console.log(pickPositionCartographic.latitude * (180/Math.PI));
}
```

Based on [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cesium-dev/fvAR2rLssJs).

Also try to check if camera is looking at the map, and not a the sky.

**SCENE2D:**

This is a simple 2D view with camera pointing directly down.

From docs:

> 2D mode. The map is viewed top-down with an orthographic projection

```
var camPos = viewer.camera.positionCartographic; 
console.log(camPos.longitude * (180/Math.PI)); 
console.log(camPos.latitude * (180/Math.PI));
```

Remaining case is **2.5D or COLUMBUS_VIEW**

Comment: Good answer.  For the case where the camera is not looking at the map/globe, you should test if `(pickPosition === undefined)` prior to using the value in `cartesianToCartographic`.

Comment: I'm using a 2D map, and using the ´getMapCenter()´ function that was suggested, but I always get ´pickPosition === undefined´.
I'm not sure what I could do to get the right position, I dont think that the camera is not looking at the map... It is on the screen.

Comment: In simple case if you are not rotating camera and always looking down on the map then you can use this:

`var camPos = viewer.camera.positionCartographic;

console.log(camPos.longitude * (180/Math.PI));

console.log(camPos.latitude * (180/Math.PI));`